# Issues with Oracle VM VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu 16.10 on my laptop. and I want to install elementary OS 0.4 on a virtual machine. so I installed Oracle VM VirtualBox on my Ubuntu system.

I am new to this virtual box stuffs. So after installation I tried to launch a new session for elementary OS. But it showed the following errors -

I tried to run the code on a terminal that the error msg showed -

> /sbin/vboxconfig

But it kept asking the password, even if I type the correct password it keeps saying that access is denied. And it seemingly falls into an infinite loop. I had to force close the terminal using the GUI (right click and close).

So what is the solution to fix it? Please help here.

[image]

Comment: If your Ubuntu has been installed in UEFI mode then you may need to disable Secure Boot. You also need to install the Extension Pack.

Comment: How did you install `Virtualbox` via `apt` or from oracle site...

Comment: @George I tried both. First I installed from Oracle site, then I installed it from terminal command. By the way, my host Ubuntu is 64 bit, but in VMbox there is not option for 64 bits, it shows 32 bits only.

Comment: That is where your problem is coming from, you are mixing the Ubuntu repo pkg and that of oracle, there is an option for 64bit in Virtualbox.

Comment: please do the fllw: first remove both __oracle's__ version and then Ubuntu's version with `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox`. When done let me know...

Comment: Then download the 64bit for Ubuntu 16.10 from [this](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.14/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924~Ubuntu~yakkety_amd64.deb) link

Comment: Note oracle's version is removed from the 1) __software center__ or using:  `dpkg --purge virtualbox-5.1` since it was not installed via `apt-get`. Change `5.1` to your version

Comment: @George I can't remove it completely. Even after running the command for removing it, in dash I can see the virtual box. I can even open it :(

Comment: Are you referring to the one from Oracle?

Comment: @George No idea, I can only see one VM still installed :'(

Comment: join me in chat!

Comment: https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Lenovo-B-and-G-Series-Notebooks/Enable-Intel-Virtual-Technology-G450/td-p/241423

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the *error message* you have installed both versions of *Virtualbox*, one from Oracle and the other from Ubuntu repo. The two don't mix as the one from Oracle is usually more recent than the Ubuntu version.

Solution:

Steps:

1. Remove both Ubuntu and the Oracle versions, Ubuntu's via `sudo apt-get remove --purge virtualbox`, and the Oracle version via either two routes:

   - from the `Software Center` under installed applications or via the `sudo dpkg --purge virtualbox-5.1`
   - please **note** change the `5.1` to your version number, as the case may be.
2. Download `64bits` version from this [link](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.1.14/virtualbox-5.1_5.1.14-112924~Ubuntu~yakkety_amd64.deb).

   - Note the link given above will download file directly, so go [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads) to see the source of that file.
3. Install using either:

   - double clicking on package, or
   - right click and select *open with software install*

Comment: Thanks. Able to remove the previous version of VM. Now installing the new one. Let's see how it turns out.

Comment: After installing it, I opened the VM. And still I see no option for Ubuntu 64bit. It's strange.

Comment: is the error gone and do you now have a working virtualbox?

Comment: Yes George, the error is now gone. Let's run a session.

Comment: Now what are you trying to do, create an elementary OS Virtual device..?

Comment: Yes. It says "This Kernel requires a X86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU. Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU".

Comment: First please accept the answer as the the solution to the error message, then did you pick the version when creating the OS from the first dialogue box?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54430/discussion-between-george-and-man-from-india).

Comment: There is no option in the first dialog box of 64 bit version. All are 32 bits.